# Mapping a continuous range into discrete bins in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, range

I've inherited maintenance of a function that takes as parameter a value between `0` and `65535` (inclusive):

`MyClass::mappingFunction(unsigned short headingIndex);`

`headingIndex` can be converted to degrees using the following formula: `degrees = headingIndex * 360 / 65536`

The role of this function is to translate the `headingIndex` into 1 of 36 symbols representing various degrees of rotation, i.e. there is a symbol for 10 degrees, a symbol for 20 degrees etc, up to 360 degrees in units of 10 degrees.

A headingIndex of 0 would translate to displaying the 0 (360) degree symbol.

The function performs the following which I can't seem to get my head around:

```
const int MAX_INTEGER = 65536;
const int NUM_SYMBOLS = 36;
int symbolRange = NUM_SYMBOLS - 1;
int roundAmount = MAX_INTEGER / (symbolRange + 1) - 1;
int roundedIndex = headingIndex + roundAmount;
int symbol = (symbolRange * roundedIndex) / MAX_INTEGER;
```

I'm confused about the algorithm that is being used here, specifically with regard to the following:

1. The intention behind `roundAmount`?  I understand it is essentially dividing the maximum input range into discrete chunks but to then add it on to the `headingIndex` seems a strange thing to do.
2. `roundedIndex` is then the original value now offset or rotated by some offset in a clockwise direction?

The algorithm produces results such as:

```
headingIndex of 0     --> symbol 0
headingIndex of 100   --> symbol 1
headingIndex of 65500 --> symbol 35
```

I'm thinking there must be a better way of doing this?

Comment: Note that `symbolRange` and `roundAmmount` are both constant expressions as well. `roundAmount` can be simplified to `(MAX_INTEGER / NUM_SYMBOLS) - 1`. I'm not sure what the reasoning behind that value is, but it looks to me like a rounding factor. A factor you add to an `int` so that decimal truncation results in a value that is equivalent to the value you would get from doing a different rounding on the original value. For example in integer arithmetic `(x + 9) / 10` functionally is `x / 10` while rounding up instead of truncating. I'm just not sure how `roundAmount` is meant to do.

Comment: It is unclear how a `headingIndex` of 100 should give a symbol of 1. According to your first formula, that would be `100 * 360 / 65536` = ~0.549 degrees, giving a symbol index of 0.

Comment: Unless I copied and pasted wrong, 0-53 map to 0, 54-1925 map to 1, 1926-3798 map to 2, and so on. That looks like a questionable mapping to me, with one interval of only 54 elements, and the others alternating between 1872 and 1873 (while 655536/36 = 1820). It also seems to have no apparent relation to your formula.

Comment: @molbdnilo Unless we both copied wrong! 0-53 give 0 then 54 gives 1. #confirmed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think the code may be confused. It looks like it's some kind of 'rounder upper'. The thing you add on to make truncation round up. (x+7)/8 truncated rounds up!
Add that value to the index then the expression (as they do) then `(NUM_SYMBOLS*roundAmount)/MAX_INTEGER` will show some rounding like behaviour. But they multiply by `(NUM_SYMBOLS-1)` and it all comes out a bit funny and we didn't want a round up anyway!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shown code looks *very* convoluted (it is possibly a guard against integer overflow). A far simpler way to determine the symbol number would be code like the following:

```cpp
    symbol = (headingIndex * 36u) / 65536u;
```

However, if this *does* present problems with integer overflow, then the calculation could be done in `double` precision, converting the result back to `int` after rounding:

```cpp
    symbol = static_cast<int>( ((headindIndex * 36.0) / 65536.0) + 0.5 ); // Add 0.5 for rounding.
```

Comment: This gives `0` for `headIndex=100`, not `1`, so it's not equivalent.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I agree it's not equivalent but, IMHO, it gives the *correct* index for any value in the `0` thru `65535` range, if that's a *linear* scale where 65535 corresponds to 360 degrees, and symbol #35.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Is overflow possible on platforms with a 16-bit `int`? But I agree that would make `const int MAX_INTEGER = 65536;` a bit daft!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think I misread your previous comment, or maybe you missed out a "not" from it? As in: *The original code does **not** have the risk of an overflow,...*

Comment: @AdrianMole Edit : Nevermind, I misunderstood the significance of `headingIndex`.

Answer (score 2):

You have 65536 possible inputs (0..65535) and 36 outputs (0..35).  That means each output bin should represent about 1820 inputs if they are divided equally.

The above formula doesn't do that.  Only the first 54 values are in bin 0, then they are equally divided across the remaining 35 bins (MAX_INTEGER/symbolRange).   About 1872 per bin.

To show this, solve for the lowest value of heading where symbol is 1.   1 * 65536 = 35 * (headingIndex + 1819) so headingIndex == 53.

Comment: I want to upvote this. What you say is right. But you haven't offered an answer so I'm not sure I should.

Comment: I don't know whether the formula is wrong or not.  It's possible that the odd mapping is a system requirement.  I am only explaining what the function does, as the comments up to when I wrote this were assuming something else.

Comment: I don't know if it's wrong either. That's why I kinda want to upvote your answer. Stuff it. If someone wants to moan about 'rules' let them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the output the same but tidy it up. Walk away.
There are odd features of that method that may or may not be what is desired.

The range for `headingIndex` of 0 - 53 gives a `symbol` of 0. That's a bucket (AKA bin) of 54 values.
The range of 63717 - 65535 give 35. That bucket is 1819 values.
All the other buckets are either 1872 or 1873 values so seem 'big'.

We can't have equal sized buckets because number of values is 65536 and 65536/36 is 1820 and 16 remainder.
So we need to bury the 16 among the buckets. They have to be uneven in size.

Notice the constant `MAX_INTEGER` is a red herring. The max is 65535. 65536 is the range. The chosen name is misleading from the start.

Why:

```
int symbolRange = NUM_SYMBOLS - 1;
int roundAmount = MAX_INTEGER / (symbolRange + 1) - 1;
```

when the second line could be `int roundAmount = MAX_INTEGER / MAX_SYMBOLS - 1;`

It doesn't look quite thought through is all I'm saying. But looks can be deceptive.

What also bothers me is the 'obvious' method proposed in other answers works great!

```
int symbol=(NUM_SYMBOLS*headingIndex)/(MAX_INTEGER);
```

Gives us buckets of either 1820 or 1821 with an even distribution. I'd say that's the natural solution to the head question.

So why the current method? Is it some artefact of some measuring device?
I'll put money the maximum value is 65535 because that's the maximum value of an unsigned 16-bit integer.

It's right to wonder about overflow. But if you're working in 16-bits it's already broken. So I wonder about a device that is recording 16-bits. That's quite realistic.

This is similar to what I know as "The Instalments Problem".
We want to the customer to pay £655.36 over 36 months. Do they pay £18.20 a month totalling £655.20 and we forget the 16p? They won't pay £18.21 totalling £655.56 and overpay 20p. Bigger first payment of £18.36 and then 35 of £18.20?
People wrestle with this one. The business answers are 'get the money' - bigger first payment. Avoid complaints if they owe you money (big last payment) and forget the pennies (all same - we're bigger than a few pence!).

In arithmetic terms for a measurement (such as degrees) I'd say the sprinkled method offered is the most natural, even and distributes the anomaly evenly.

But it's not the only answer. Up to you. Hint: If you haven't been ask to fix this and just think it's ugly - walk away. Walk away now.